# What is the proper way to light a scene for the Hololens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

We have built an app for the Hololens that has 1 or 2 3D characters in the scene at any given time.  What is the best practice for adding lighting to an AR scene for headsets like the Hololens?  Should the scene be lighted at all?

Comment: Some useful design based considerations are given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/color%2C-light-and-materials).  Lighting will be needed for any unity application that does not use unlit shaders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's the thing with the Hololens:

## Black is Transparent

This means that any *shadows* on objects will make the object fade out into transparency when viewed on the real device (the emulator does not show simulated environments). As such, environments should be brightly lit from a source that is a child of the main camera (you may still use a directional light pointing from above angle) and objects should not cast shadows (as it will appear that those shadows are punching holes in objects).

This also means that you will want textures that are brightly colored as well.

Brightly lit (real world) backgrounds will exacerbate the transparency effect (as the Hololens can't reduce incoming light).

You'll likely have to experiment to find something that works best for your project.